# Free radical bromonation of 1-ethyl-4-nitrobenzene

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

In the above reaction , I am confused between . Among them which is major product and why .

[image]

Comment: The key is the relative stability of each alkyl radical formed as an intermediate in the reaction. This is explained rather well in [Bruice's Organic Chemistry](https://www.pearsonhighered.com/product/Bruice-Organic-Chemistry-7th-Edition/9780321803221.html), 7th edition, section 13.4, pp. 561-563.

Comment: @AdityaSher but there will be more ellect of NO2 (-I , -M)

Comment: Oops sorry I just missed that! Let me work on it

Answer (score 2):

This is would be a free radical bromination reaction. Bromine is very selective. ***It is going to replace the hydrogen from the highest substituted carbon***. So according to me second one should be the answer i.e. Br attached to secondary carbon.

Hope it helps

Comment: but there will be more effect of NO2 (-I , -M)